# TRIGGERS_function

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle10g

please help me to find the solution i have a project .

so my project is about a mobile repair store , we have some tables :

`customers`, `mobiles`, `repairjob`

```
//customer table
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
 CUSTOMER_CPR NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
MID VARCHAR2(30)
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
 EMAIL VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 HOME_TEL NUMBER(8) UNIQUE,
HOUSE_NO VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
ROAD_NO VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
BLOCK_NO VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
CITY VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
);

//mobiles table 
CREATE TABLE MOBILES (
    MOB_ID NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    MODEL VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    MOB_DECRIPTION VARCHAR2(100),
    SERIAL_NUM VARCHAR2(30) UNIQUE,
    MAKE VARCHAR2(50),
customer_cpr number(9),
);


//repair job table
CREATE TABLE REPAIR JOB (
 JOB_NUM NUMBER primary key,
customer_cpr number(9)
 EMP_ID NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL,
 DATE_RECEIVED DATE,
 DATE_TO_RETURN DATE,
ITEM_ID NUMBER

);
```

so my question is to make a trigger function , we have assumed that the customer cannot have more than 3 repair jobs or can't fix more than 3 mobiles at one time  until it finishes all. so how i make a triiger function ?

Comment: Triggers and functions are two different things - sounds like what you are looking for is a trigger.

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.